# Where should I handle entity property collection in clean architecture

Tags: repository, entity, clean-architecture

**Clean Architecture Question:**

I have an entity `A` that have a collection of entity `B` Inside it

Like this:

```
// Entity
class A {
  id,
  bArr: B[]
}

// Entity B
class B {
  // Some Props
}
```

How do I manage the `bArr` Collection?

- Do I manage it inside `A` Repository?
- Create another Repository for managing the collection like *First Class Collections*?
- Another option?

Comment: What do you mean by managing 'bArr` ?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov update specific item and add, delete and get on the collection

Comment: What is the problem when you put it inside `A`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to have a single repository for both entities. I recommend reading about "Unit of Work" pattern.